# Led cube 4*4*4 with anodes horizontally

Tags: led

I want to create an Led Cube 4x4x4 with an ATMEGA 16 chip.
Because is my first electronic project, I connect leds on layers(horizontally) with     common anodes and vertically with common cathodes.

Can you tell me please, what's the differences and how can I continue(if is possible)?
I have bought 16 resistors of 220 ohms and 4 transistors 2N222 instead of BC337. Can you tell me, please, if I can use these components without recreate the Cube?
Thank you.

Edited:
This is the schematic I followed at the beginning of the project but now I don't know if is possible anymore.I'm sorry that isn't in that format, but it takes a lot of time to add all leds and pins of uC.[image]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Please draw a schematic diagram.

Comment: A schematic is better than words. You can add one in using the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar. Double-click a component to edit its properties. 'R' = rotate, 'H' = horizontal flip. 'V' = vertical flip. 

Note that when you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar an editable schematic is saved in your post. That makes it easy for us to copy and edit in our answers. You don't need a CircuitLab account, no screengrabs, no image uploads, no background grid.

Comment: If this is your first project, I recommend building a known working design, like this: https://www.jameco.com/Jameco/workshop/JamecoBuilds/4x4x4ledcube.html

Comment: I followed this tutorial for making the Led Cube. [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0qYi1MYT5Lk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0qYi1MYT5Lk)

Comment: And this is the complete tutorial https://www.instructables.com/id/LED-CUBE-4X4X4-USING-ARDUINO-UNO/

Comment: The schematic that you posted looks basically the same as the Jameco schematic, so it should work. I didn't see any transistors in the tutorials that you linked to. Modern LEDs are quite bright with only a few mA, maybe that is the answer. I would use 4 transistors. Jameco specifies 2.2k for the base resistor, you may need to go lower if the transistor isn't saturating well. I would use a 470 with a 2N2222.

Comment: Many people here won't help unless they have an easily readable schematic. If you have more questions, you should draw a 2 x 2 x 2 cube using CircuitLab. You don't need to draw all 64 LEDs to get your point across.

Answer (score 1):

> 4 transistors 2N222 instead of BC337

The [2N2222](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/P2N2222A-D.PDF) is 600 mA max and [BC337](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/BC337-D.PDF) is 800 mA max.
Either will work fine, and with plenty of overhead.

---

> Can you tell me, please, if I can use these components without
>   recreate the Cube?

You do not need to make a cube out of the LEDs.
The 220 Ω resistors are what is recommended.